# Using mqtt with Vite

Tags: vue.js, mqtt, vite

I need to use the [MQTT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) npm package in a Vue app using Vite. In order to get the package to work in the browser, the developer documents two methods: using browserify and webpack. Since I am using vite, I don't know how to export the library so I can use it.

Comment: I would suggest using [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/js/index.php) - you can import the MQTT client through a CDN and thus avoid all of Browserify, Webpack and Vite.

Answer (score 0):

Add MQTT Alias to your vite.config.js like:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import { config } from "dotenv";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx(), config()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      mqtt: 'mqtt/dist/mqtt.js',
    }
  }
})
```